# Overload a virtual method in a derived class so it takes more parameters in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I have an abstract class `A` with the pure virtual method `void foo(int a) = 0`

Then I have several classes that inherit from `A` and all of them define the method `foo`. But I need one of them, `B`, to make it so `foo` takes an extra parameter, `int b`, so sort of an overload.

Then I would like to do this:

```
A *bInstance = new B();
bInstance -> foo(1, 2);
```

But I get an error telling me that `foo` is taking too many parameters.

Writing this, I realize it's kind of a weird thing to do so maybe you can't do this and it's good that you can't do it. But in case it is possible, please do tell me how I should go about it.

Comment: Why would you want this? I mean, why use a common base if the derived class has another interface? This seems design smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the overloaded function of B only if the pointer to use is of type B.

See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A{
public:
  virtual void foo(int a) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void foo(int a) override
    {

    }
    void foo(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << a << "," << b;
    }
};

int main(){
    auto b = std::make_shared<B>();
    b->foo(1, 2);
    
    //to use a:
    A* aPtr = b.get();
    aPtr->foo(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, thank you! It makes sense, when the pointer is of type A the compiler goes to declaration of foo inside class A and sees only 1 parameter

Comment: Yeah, for further inheritance you should add a virtual destructor. And you might should use std::make_unique or simple stack alloc.

Comment: I would prefer `std::shared_ptr<A> aPtr{b};` for consistency with what you yourself proposed and safety - extracting a raw pointer isn't very fortunate (may tempt to delete it causing segfault).

Answer (score 0):

Although Bernd's answer is a possiblility, you must ask yourself what the effect of an overload is. E.g., think of the following.

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<A> bAsA = std::make_unique<B>();
bAsA->foo(1, 2); // no worky.
bAsA->foo(1); // works, but what should it do?
```

It there's a different interface between `A` and `B`, I would suggest to add a layer of abstraction in form of a new base class (which I will call `C`).

So instead of

```cpp
struct A {
    // common
    virtual void bar() {}
    // class specific
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

struct B: public A {
    // weird unused override which is still available
    void foo(int) override {}
    // class specific
    void foo(int, int) {}
};
```

use

```cpp
struct C {
    // common
    virtual void bar() {}
};

struct A: public C {
    // class specific
    virtual void foo(int) = 0;
};

struct B: public C {
    // class specific
    void foo(int, int) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fully achieve want you want using a default parameter:

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual void foo(int a, int b = 0) = 0;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    void foo(int a, int b) override { }
};

class C : public A
{
    public:
    void foo(int a, int b = 0) override { }
};

int main()
{
    A* b = new B();
    A* c = new C();

    b->foo(1, 2);
    c->foo(1);
}
```

You don't have to use this parameter in `C::foo` implementation (and any other derived classes) if you don't need to.